# Excel:Use of Lookup functions to display values

Tags: excel, vba

I have a dropdown(added using data validation) in column "A" in sheet1 which has some 10 items added to it, and B and C column which are empty, and I have a list of values in sheet "Sheet2" in columns A,B and C, here I`ve displayed values from "A" into the dropdown(Sheet1,"A" column), my actual work to do here is when I select first item in dropdown, I have to display  first value from sheet2 from B and C into B and C in sheet1.

I thought of writing macro by adding values into arrays.But then I thought of using lookup functions.

Please tell me how can I achive this by using "lookup" functions?

Comment: It seems like you have to use VBA macro to achieve your goal. Rgds,

Comment: Check Excel Help for VLOOKUP() - it should do what you need. If you run into problems, update your post with what you tried and describe what happened.

Comment: OK. Do you think adding items to arrays and continueing is good?

Comment: Like Tim said, just use the VLOOKUP formula and if you run into issues, update your question with what you have tried.

Comment: I made it work myself by using arrays.